# What is the best way for generating a saveable image from html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, input

[image]
ticket information with given inputs(name surname) and opened in new tab as image

1)There will be a input screen in which user fill with name, surname and country
2) when click submit button, I want it to open in new tab as the filled informations added on a ticket template.. I can create it functionally with javascript but the QUESTION is;
how to show it to user as image?

Comment: *I can create it functionally with javascript..* <-- What, exactly, do you wind up creating?

Comment: I am gonna create a souvenir tickets for a holly day.. can you please give me topics to search?

Comment: That's not what I asked. You said you created it functionally. What exactly did you wind up creating?

Comment: I mean, I can bind input and output text over the ticket image. But it shown in the website as html page in which image and texts are not combinde. user can not save it as image.

Comment: The way I would do it is post back to the server, generate the image there, and then redirect the client to a URL where they can view the generated image

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could look into a pdf library like jsPDF. From pdf you could go into other formats.